# Pool de Conexiones +?

Tags: java

Chicos tengo una duda, recientemente he colocado un pool de conexiones en mi app en java usando commons.dbcp2+pool+loggin y cada vez que me conecto a mi base de datos utilizo

`dataSource.getConnection();` , hasta este punto no hay problema.

mi Problema es Sincronizar o utilizar el Pool por las diferentes ejecuciones del sistema.

Explico: 
Suponiendo que el sistema se ejecute por 10, 20, 50 personas diferentes; como hago para que todos trabajen bajo un mismo Pool que gestione todas las comunicaciones de todos los usuarios?

Debo implementarlo con Sockets y que mi Servidor envíe los `.getConnection();` a los clientes
o se debe solicitar a un JNDI previamente configurado, o usar glassfish?

Estos últimos puntos no lo tengo muy claro.

Comment: ¿Es una aplicación cliente-servidor o web?

Comment: cliente - servidor. Por lo que estuve leyendo, lo que planteo se puede hacer normalmente en Java EE usando Glassfish,tomcat,etc. Pero para Java SE aun no doy con una respuesta. Si ejecuto 100 veces el sistema, son 100 instancias diferentes por lo que el pool se abre 100 veces diferentes

Comment: Ese es el punto: Un pool de conexiones en el cliente es absurdo. El cliente sólo necesita una conexión.

Comment: Eso lo comprendo, por ello realizo mi consulta. Si tengo una aplicación estandar la cual el cliente realiza conexiones a la BD para las transacciones. Lo que deseo es que cada una de ellas pasen por un servidor, por eso pregunto que si es posible con Socket o que alternativa tengo en java se

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres que “pasen por un servidor”? ¿Cuál es tu preocupación?

Comment: La verdad tras unas horas de análisis y replantear mi necesidad, tu pregunta me hace entender que no requiero que cada solicitud "pase por un servidor" puesto que cada cliente solo necesita de 1 única conexión y con el Pool la reutilizo para evitar cerrar y crear.  <Act.> Por otro lado, la función mas que necesidad sería evitar entregar la información de la base de datos a los usuarios en el código, pero para mi app. no tendría mayor problema. Por lo que, gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: Exacto! Te invito a que publiques tu propia respuesta y la aceptes.

Answer (score 0):

Tras investigar y con el apoyo de varios cibernautas. 
En cierto Punto está mal planteado mi pregunta y el presunto problema te "tenía".

Sucede que para una aplicación Cliente-Servidor no requiero implementar un "servidor" para gestionar la comunicación dado que cada cliente utiliza una única conexión para todas sus transacciones, y en este sentido, **bastaría con implementar un pool** para evitar crear una conexión y eliminarla cada vez.

Entonces mi error era de concepto ya que contemplaba implementar algo similar para Java EE como un pool administrador por glassfish,tomcat,etc.

Gracias por la colaboración.